# How to get eigenvalues as a Vector listed in order of magnitude using MathNet Numerics?

Tags: c#, vector, eigenvector, mathnet-numerics

I used the Evd<> class of MathNet Numerics to get the eigenvector of a matrix but it turned out to be of type `Vector<Complex>` and I was unable to cast that into `Vector<double>`, which is what I need for my operations.

This is how I got the eigenvector:

```
DenseMatrix processedData = someData;
Evd<> eigen = processedData.evd();
Vector<Complex> eigenvector = (Vector<Complex>)eigen.EigenValues;
```

When I tried casting as '`Vector<double>`' the program wouldn't accept it.
Is there a way to get the eigenvector of a matrix in `Vector<double>`?

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to declare all the types explicitly (instead of use var, selectively) with Math.NET Numerics v3 you need to open the following namespaces:

```
using System.Numerics
using MathNet.Numerics
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization
```

There is usually no need to open the type-specific namespaces like `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double` as it is recommended to use the generic `Matrix<T>` type only when refering to a matrix or vector. This way there is no need to cast between them (as you did in your example) at all.

Then the example looks like this:

```
Matrix<double> processedData = Matrix<double>.Build.Random(5,5);
Evd<double> eigen = processedData.Evd();
Vector<Complex> eigenvector = eigen.EigenValues;
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! - I had typed Vector<double> but I had forgotten to format it as code. I'm trying to change the Complex type into type double so that I can perform regular operations on it.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it just the [EigenVectors](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Factorization/Evd.cs) property of the same class?

```
public abstract class Evd<T> : ISolver<T>
where T : struct, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the eigen values (λ) of matrix in ascending value.
    /// </summary>
    public Vector<Complex> EigenValues { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets eigenvectors.
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix<T> EigenVectors { get; private set; }
}
```

Docs here: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization/Evd%601.htm#EigenVectors

A real NxN matrix will have up to N (not necessarily unique) real eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, thus both need to be returned in arrays; a *complex* NxN matrix will have exactly N (not necessarily unique) eigenvalues with corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors are related but different things.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, nevertheless the last sentence says "Is there a way to get the eigenvector in Vector?"

Comment: Indeed, seems it's me misunderstanding the question. Ignore my comment above. Seems there is some confusion there between eigenvalues and -vectors in the question (vs. title).

Comment: Well, between the two of us both plausible interpretations of the question got answered, so that's good.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! - I had typed Vector<double> but I had forgotten to format it as code. I'm trying to change the Complex type into type double so that I can perform regular operations on it.